# Create FTP dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, ftp

When User registered, I need to create one folder for that user in the server and create FTP for that folder in PHP.

How can I create FTP username,  password and how it will assign that FTP to particular folder

I have access for WHM. Anyone guide me

Comment: I doubt you can do this via pure php-code (but maybe it is possible if WHM API allowing config changes. idk). I suggest, this question more for admin, there is needs to be a pack of scripts that can create a new ftp-records inside the server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about WHM, but if it's a cloud solution it should provide an API.

I've found some more info about this here

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/UAPI+Functions+-+Ftp%3A%3Aadd_ftp

then you'll probably need to learn the WHM api works

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Guide+to+WHM+API+1

and then you'll need how to use curl or some rest api client

http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

again, I'm not sure which client is the best to use with WHM,

but I found this

https://github.com/tcdent/php-restclient

I'm not sure if I can help you here.

Answer (score 0):

I followed below URL with Cpanel access, It working great :)
https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/cpanel-api-to-create-ftp-accounts.144121/